# How to use .submit() to submit a form with document.forms object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I've got this form:

```
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Where inside there's this button:

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="8861" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
```

I'm trying to submit the form using the `submit()` function of the `forms` object.

```
document.forms[1].submit();
```

The `index` of the form is `1` (that's ok), but still it's not working: the page gets recharged, but the form doesn't send any data.

Would be great if somebody could give me a hand.

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide what your action looks like ? "....centenary-white-matt-bevelled-herringbone-mosaic-testing/"

Comment: Where are you calling that code? Note that you shouldn't need any JavaScript to submit the form with a submit button...

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering @heretic-monkey I want to submit the form through a button outside of the form itself. That is why I'm looking to do it through JS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear what data you're expecting and what fields are in the form. You say "Where inside there's this button:", but now you're telling me the button is not actually inside the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The page gets recharged but the form doesn't send any data.

Your problem is that when a form is submitted, only **successful** controls will be included in the data sent with it.

A submit button is only a successful control if it is used to submit the form. You're using JavaScript instead.

Move the `name` and `value` from the submit button to an `<input type="hidden">` which will **always** be successful.